# Java Project changing behaviour

Tags: java, swing, graphics, jframe, jpanel

I have been working on a basic Java Swing application, that paints some objects into a opaque JPanel. I have been coding this app on a University MAC-PC. Yesterday I tested the program on my macbook air(after exporting the project), the behaviour of the application totally change.

The logic of the application is as follows, a Jframe that contains a JLayeredPaneL with Jpanel, in each Jpanel I paint some objects.The application is working correctly on the University laptop.

1)The JPanel is not longer transparent

```
//Creating Layered Panel
JLayeredPane lpane = new JLayeredPane();
lpane.setBounds(0, 0, screenSize.width, screenSize.height);
this.add(lpane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
lpane.setBounds(0, 0, screenSize.width, screenSize.height);
//creating Jpanel
myGlassPane = new JPanel()
myGlassPane.setBackground(new Color(0, 255, 0, 0));
myGlassPane.setBounds(0, 0, 400, 400);
myGlassPane.setOpaque(true);
myGlassPane.setVisible(true);
//adding item
lpane.add(myGlassPane);
this.setBackground(new Color(0, 255, 0, 0));//makes JFrame invisible
this.setVisible(true);  
this.setResizable(false);
```

2) The JPanel does not remember what is previously drawn(it actually creates two Jpanel one what is being drawn at the moment and what was previously drawn)

I paint lines, whenever a new line is added to an array I call paintAgain(), here is the code of the paintComponent

```
public void paintLines(Point p)
{
    arrayLines.add(p);
    repaint();
    //Only the point is displayed the other points are not visible,
    //the other points are in another JPANEL?
}

public void delete() 
{

    delete = true;
    arrayLines.clear();
    repaint();
}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) 
{ 
    super.paintComponent(g);

    if(delete)
    {
        g.clearRect(0,0,screenSize.width,screenSize.height);
        delete =false;
    }
    else
    {
        g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
    g2d.setStroke(new BasicStroke(10));
    g2d.setColor(pickedColor);
    //It just paints the new lines, it does not iterate through all the points

    g2d.draw(new Line2D.Float(arrayLines.get(arraySize-1).getx1(), arrayLines.get(arraySize-1).gety1(),arrayLines.get(arraySize-1).getx2(),arrayLines.get(arraySize-1).gety2()));
    }

 }
```

I do not know why the behaviour of the program changes. Maybe the JRE version that i'm using?I have literally no idea since, it has never happened before

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3):

In your paintComponent method, your code as written just draws one line, and so one line is all that you see. Instead you need to use a for loop to iterate through your Point collection, arrayLines, drawing a line between points.

```
// note that i *must* start at 1, not at 0
for (int i = 1; i < arrayLines.size(); i++) {
   int x1 = arrayLines.get(i - 1).x;
   int y1 = arrayLines.get(i - 1).y;
   int x2 = arrayLines.get(i).x;
   int y2 = arrayLines.get(i).y;
   g2.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2);
}
```

Also, where do you set `delete` to true ever?

---

**Edit**
Regarding your comments:

> ...The paint method is an example, I call paintLines() several times.

This won't matter if paintComponent draws one and only one line.

> Do I have to repaint everything , everytime i make a modification in the array?

At this point, probably, yes. Later consider doing your static background drawing to a BufferedImage and then displaying that in the paintComponent almost first thing, right after the `super.paintComponent(g)` call, and then drawing your non-static, your moving sprites directly in paintComponent. If you know for a fact that you've only altered a portion of a component, you can call one of the `repaint(...)` overload methods that suggest repainting a rectangular area of the component.

> The problem is this code is working in another computer and in mine it misbehaves.

The issue for me is that I have no idea why the code would have a prayer of working on another system since it is broken code.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer.Sorry i did not finish the delete method. The paint method is an example, I call paintLines() several times. Do I have to repaint everything , everytime i make a modification in the array? The problem is this code is working in another computer and in mine it misbehaves.

Comment: @IgnacioFerrero: you're very welcome. Please see edits to answer.

Comment: The op is using an alpha color for the background on an opaque component (myGlassPane) which is going to cause issues

Answer (score 3):

One of the other issues you are having is the fact that you are using an alpha based color as the background to an opaque component...

```
myGlassPane = new JPanel()
myGlassPane.setBackground(new Color(0, 255, 0, 0));
myGlassPane.setBounds(0, 0, 400, 400);
myGlassPane.setOpaque(true);
myGlassPane.setVisible(true);
//adding item
lpane.add(myGlassPane);
```

Swing only knows how to paint opaque or transparent components and makes these decisions based on the opaque state of the components.

When transparent, the API knows that it must first prepare the graphics context properly and secondly, paint all components that might be beneath this one.

When using an alpha based background color, the component is unable to clear the `Graphics` context for painting (as filling with a transparent color doesn't do anything), this tends to mean that the `Graphics` context still contains what ever was painted to it previously (as the `Graphics` context is a shared resource).

Instead, remove...

```
myGlassPane.setBackground(new Color(0, 255, 0, 0));
```

and use

```
myGlassPane.setOpaque(false);
```

which will give you the same effect.

It will also mean you won't need

```
g.clearRect(0,0,screenSize.width,screenSize.height);
```

and can simply remove the all the elements from the `arrayLines` instead, which will give you the same effect...just longer lasting...